# instance for RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption Text missing when using (=~)

Tags: haskell

I try to find a way to use regex to search in text and not adding a dependency for template haskell. 
My simplistic example is

```
import Text.Regex.TDFA

d = t1 =~ pat4 :: Text
pat4 = "([12][0,6-9][0-9][0-9])" :: Text
t1 = "foodiebar 1933 some more 19456 text " :: Text
```

The code works for `Text.Regex.PCRE` for `String` but when I change to Text and import `Text.Regex.TDFA` the compiler produces:

```
RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption Text
```

what is additionally required?

Answer (score 0):

Missing is an import of the instances in `Text.Regex.TDFA.Text` (only the instances). Thus:

```
import Text.Regex.TDFA
import Text.Regex.TDFA.Text ()
```

It is unfortunate that there is so little up-to-date documentation and two many different implementations of regex for haskell. I took hours to identify which packages work together.

I found the [blog](https://gabebw.com/blog/2015/10/11/regular-expressions-in-haskell) useful.